# split regex with optional delimiters

Tags: java, regex, delimiter

~separate text fields~ and ^ separate all fields

String being inputed (fields can be empty)

```
~01001~^~0100~^~Butter, salted~^~BUTTER,WITH SALT~^~~^~~^~Y~^~~^0^~~^6.38^4.27^8.79^3.87
```

My current split

```
String [] splited = str.split("\\^",-1);
        for (String s : splited){
            System.out.println (s);
        }
```

Output

```
~01001~
~0100~
~Butter, salted~
~BUTTER,WITH SALT~
~~
~~
~Y~
~~
0
~~
6.38
4.27
8.79
3.87
```

How do change the regex so that ~~ are not included? (empty fields are fine)

What I want the output to be

```
01001
0100
Butter, salted
BUTTER,WITH SALT


Y

0

6.38
4.27
8.79
3.87
```

Empty lines should be ""

Comment: Use or ~~ in your regex

Comment: include the `~` character in your regex to capture if there are any like :str.split("~?\\^~?",-1)` or `str.split("~*\\^",-1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting won't be appropriate to get rid of those tildes. You will want either to replace `~(.*?)~` with `\1` or to use basic detection (`charAt`) and manipulation (`subString`)

Comment: Yeah I'm just gonna do this.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex to match the data you want:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("~([^~]*)~|([^\\^]+)");
```

and get the matched data using `Matcher` API.

```
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
   System.out.println(m.groupCount() == 2 ? m.grop(2) : m.grop(1));
}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rH9yO5/4)

Comment: This still leaves `~` when they can't be considered as separators (i.e. in the beginning and end of the string), since split uses its pattern as a separator.

Comment: And it ignores empty lines, which I don't know if OP is ok with. I think using split isn't a good idea here, anyway I guess your answer is valid.

Comment: I don't want to get rid of the ~~ completely I want them to be empty fields instead.

Comment: I commend your effort but I think doing a first split around `^` then getting rid of the `~` really is more sane here ;)

Comment: ok after OP edited question, I have edited and changed my answer completely. See edited one now.

Comment: Yeah I'm just gonna search through the array and remove the ~~ thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear how ~ are treated, but it seems simple enough to just put both characters as a split character:

```
        String b[] = str.split("[\\^~]");
```

Which essentially ignores all ~ and ^ characters.